# If $A$ is connected , $B$ is open and closed and $A \cap B$ is non empty then $A \subset B$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A,B \subset X$. If $A$ is connected , $B$ is open and closed and $A \cap B$ is non empty then $A \subset B$.

I tried it with proving a contradiction if we first assume that $A \not\subset B$.

But I cannot do with it. Please help.

Comment: In a connected topological space, the only open and closed subsets are the empty set and the entire space itself.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$, and we have that $A\cap B\subseteq A$.  Since $B$ is open and closed in $X$ then by the subspace topology $A\cap B$ is going to be open and closed in $A$.  Since this set is nonempty and $A$ is connected we must have that $A\cap B = A$, thus $A \subseteq B$.

Answer (score 0):

think of the relative topology on A in connection with the disjoint partition:
$$
A = (A\cap B) \cup (A \cap \bar B)
$$
where $\bar B$, the complement of $B$, is also both open and closed.

recall the definition of *connected*